# Binding List of Lists with ASP.NET Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding

I have an issue about complex model binding in ASP.NET. I have currently that model
I send to my view a `List <P>`

```
public class P
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Guid Uid {get;set;}

    public List<ChildItem> Items {get;set;}
}
```

And i need to only modify one field in my `ChildItem` but display many fields (the `P.Name` and some of the fields from each `ChildItem`) and submit the whole model (the `List <P>` with edited values)

How can i achieve this kind of binding with the Html Helpers provided by ASP.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimum solution is to use editor templates and display templates. Here is a good tutorial. [How to use EditorTemplates](http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/).

Comment: Thanks i read some articles about that, but that one seems to be really clear

Comment: Generally for simple case Editor templates works perfect. If you want rich or modified markup for all same cases throughout your application, then look to write your own Html Helper. Its pretty simple and helpful.